# NestJS CLI project running error on terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

An error showing on running the command `yarn start:dev` on my webstorm built-in terminal

**Error Screenshot**

[image]

**Here is my `package.json` file**

```
{
  "name": "test-project",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nodemon",
    "start:debug": "nodemon --config nodemon-debug.json",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^6.10.14",
    "@nestjs/core": "^6.10.14",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^6.10.14",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.4",
    "uuid": "^7.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^6.13.2",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^6.8.1",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^6.10.14",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.2",
    "@types/jest": "25.1.2",
    "@types/node": "^13.1.6",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.8",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.12.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.12.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.19.1",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "prettier": "^1.18.2",
    "supertest": "^4.0.2",
    "ts-jest": "25.2.0",
    "ts-loader": "^6.2.1",
    "ts-node": "^8.6.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.9.0",
    "typescript": "^3.7.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".spec.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

I'm trying to solve but I couldn't figure out the code!

Comment: The error **says port already in use**, seems you are having another application running on port **3000**.

Comment: Several time I have to change the port and its work !!

Comment: Glad to hear that its working for you now, when you get this issue again I suggest that you logout/restart machine if it persist that always work for me.

Comment: I'm going to do that! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Happens when the nodemon process abruptly ends / close the terminal. Normally end up using a different port number or restart the system. You can kill the nodemon process running on port 3000 by running the following command:

```
kill -9 $(lsof -t -i:3000)
```